# using Scala 2.10.1 Value Types in Java

Tags: java, scala, compiler-errors, value-type

I am updating my 2.9.* project to 2.10.  I have several classes for fundamental types (angles, lengths, etc) that seem like they are perfect candidates for value types.  Unfortunately, my Java code that uses these types is not compiling, and I can't figure out why.  I have simplified it down to a very simple set of code.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**Angle class Definition (scala)**

```
package com.example.units

class Angle(val radians : Double) extends AnyVal
{
  def degrees = radians * 180.0 / math.Pi
}

object Angle
{
  val Zero = new Angle(0)
}
```

**Angle Test Case (painfully written in Java)**

```
package com.example.units;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class AngleTest
{
    @Test
    public static void TestZero()
    {
        Angle a = Angle.Zero();
        Assert.assertEquals(a.degrees(), 0, 1E-9);

    }

}
```

When I compile, I get this error:

```
AngleTest.java:19 incompatible types
found :double
required: com.example.units.Angle
Angle a = Angle.Zero();

            ^
```

It looks to me as if Angle.Zero is being returned as a double, not an Angle.  I tried adding box/unbox methods, but continue to receive the same error.  Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scala compiler turns value classes into their unboxed type, which eliminates their cost for runtime. Inspecting the compiled class file for `Angle`, you'll see:

```
public static double Zero();
```

So from Java's point of view, Angle.Zero returns a double; it's not aware of the semantics of Scala's value classes.

Angle's own methods, such as `degrees`, get compiled into a) a static extension method that takes in the unboxed value (`double`) b) an instance method:

```
public static double degrees$extension(double);
public double degrees();
```

Which means the latter can still be called on an instance of `Angle` in Java:

```
Angle a = new Angle(0);
Assert.assertEquals(a.degrees(), 0, 1E-9);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I use factory methods quite a bit in my companion classes (Angle.fromDegrees(), Angle.fromRadians(), etc) to improve readability.  Right now all of these methods have the same problem as outlined above.  It seems to me that there should be a way to make this work.

Comment: I'm definitely curious to see a way to make it work. Having tried a few workarounds, nothing seems elegant (for instance, in your Java tests, you could wrap the value received from the .Zero() call in a Angle, but that reduces readability). I think the root cause here is that Scala's value classes aren't designed for the same interoperability with Java as regular classes are; they're merely a compile-time abstraction to simplify your Scala code. I suggest using regular classes in your case.

Comment: Unfortunately I have come to the same conclusion.  If this is not a bug, then it is at least a design flaw w/ value types.  One of Scalas strengths is its ability to interop natively w/ Java code.  I will avoid using them until it is adressed.

Comment: This is spot on. You can only really devise ad-hoc solutions to this.

Comment: Do we know if there are any plans to 'fix' this?  Value Types not playing nice with Java makes them essentially useless to me.

Comment: AFAIK there are no plans at the moment to really fix this that I would put my money on. The Scala people really have their hands tied with regard to what you can do on the JVM at run time. One of those things that you can't have on the JVM at run time are value classes, so regardless of how clever they are with the compiler, until Oracle puts value classes onto the JVM itself, we're kind of stuck.

Comment: IMO Scala did it right, Java messed up. The whole concept of a distinction between "primitive" and "object" types is flawed.